# Rotated Bitmap Off Center

Tags: android, bitmap, rotation

I'm rotating an image and then displaying it in an ImageView, the problem is that after it's rotated, it's moved up and right.

My rotation code, after rotating it with this method, it's saved to the file system:

```
private Bitmap rotateImage( Bitmap original, int degrees )
{
        final int height = original.getHeight(), width = original.getWidth();

        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        matrix.setRotate( degrees, width / 2, height / 2 );
        RectF rectF = new RectF( 0, 0, width, height );
        matrix.mapRect( rectF );
        Bitmap rotatedImage = Bitmap.createBitmap( (int)rectF.width(), (int)rectF.height(), original.getConfig() );
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas( rotatedImage );
        canvas.drawBitmap( original, matrix, new Paint( Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG | Paint.DITHER_FLAG | Paint.FILTER_BITMAP_FLAG ) );

        return rotatedImage;
}
```

My code to load the saved image from the file system:

```
private Bitmap loadImage( String imagePath, int maxHeight, int maxWidth )
{
BitmapFactory.Options fOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
int fHeight, fWidth, scale;

fOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
BitmapFactory.decodeFile( imagePath, fOptions );
fHeight = fOptions.outHeight;
fWidth = fOptions.outWidth;
scale = Math.max( maxHeight > 0 ? fHeight / maxHeight : 0,
                      maxWidth > 0 ? fWidth / maxWidth : 0 );

fOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
fOptions.inSampleSize = scale;
fOptions.inPurgeable = true;

return BitmapFactory.decodeFile( imagePath, fOptions );
}
```

ImageView xml:

```
<ImageView android:id="@+id/image"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_margin="10dp"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:scaleType="centerCrop" />
```

The image is rotated just fine, but when it's displayed it is offset right and up from where it should be, and then cropped off by the ImageView as a result.  Can anybody see what's causing it to be offset?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your pivot is being calculated from the original image size, which might not be the center of your final image.

Before drawing your image I would set the matrix like so:

```
//center the source image
matrix.setTranslate(-width/2, -height/2);
//rotate the image
matrix.postRotate(degrees);
//now move it to the center of your final image
matrix.postTranslate(rotatedImage.getWidth()/2, rotatedImage.getHeight()/2);

//now draw the image
canvas.drawBitmap( original, matrix, new Paint( Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG | Paint.DITHER_FLAG | Paint.FILTER_BITMAP_FLAG ) );
```

Comment: Great, this worked, thanks.  I have another question though, obviously I don't understand the relationship between Matrix's pre, set, and post methods.  If I do it exactly as in your example, it works.  If I do `preTranslate` `setRotate` and then `postTranslate` with the same numbers, it doesn't work right.  Why not?

Comment: The different methods of modifying the matrix have to do with the way the transforms are applied mathematically. For me an easy way to keep it straight is just to apply it with a "set" for step 1, then "post" for subsequent steps. That way everything happens in a nice linear fashion and is easy to follow.

Comment: @BrianDeWolff image size get reduced and become square

Answer (score 0):

It is because the image is rotating with respect to the top left corner. After rotating the image, move it over by `width/2` and `height/2`

Comment: When I use `setRotate` on the matrix I use `width / 2` and `height / 2` to set the rotation point at the center.